# Angular JS watch won't fire when data is changed in stomp subscribe

Tags: angularjs, websocket

below i will paste my ws connection code:

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/gs-guide-websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/events/get/1', function (event) {
             $scope.event = JSON.parse(event.body).path + ": " + JSON.parse(event.body).eventType;
        });
    });
}
```

And this code above is inside controller:

```
myApp.controller('ConnectionController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
```

And below is my directive to listen on change:

```
myApp.directive('listenerEventsDirective', function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            event: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('event', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if(newValue){
                    element.append("<tr><td>" + newValue + "</td></tr>");
                    alert("newValue " + newValue);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

If i declare method like this in controller:

```
$scope.changeEvent = function(change){
    this.event = change;
}
```

everything is working, but if i try to update my value through ws subscribtion it won't work.

How can i make watch fires even if i'm changing event in stomp subscribe method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your callback is called outside angular, try wrapping it in an `$apply` method in order to trigger a digest cycle to determine changes:

```
$scope.$apply(function () {
   $scope.event = JSON.parse(event.body).path + ": " + 
      JSON.parse(event.body).eventType;
});
```